# How to filter nodes using date field

Tags: views, entities, datetime

I have a content type of "Class" that has a date field attached to it `field_class_date`.

When a node of the type "Class" is viewed, I would like to display links to other classes that are on the same day of that particular class.

I tried doing this with views, but couldn't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, **(1)** I placed code in node--class.tpl.php which retrieved the current class date

```
$date = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node)->field_class_date->value->value();
```

Then, **(2)** I modified that value to get the start of the day and the end of the day ($start and $end) in the following format: **Y-m-d H:i:s**

**(3)** Perform a query using EFQ to grab a list of the nodes that share the same date:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'class')
  ->fieldCondition('field_class_date', 'value', array($start, $end), 'BETWEEN')
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_class_date', 'value', 'ASC');
$result = $query->execute();
```

**(4)** Loop through each result and create the content I want to display later in node--class.tpl.php

```
foreach($result['node'] as $i) {
  $node = node_load($i->nid);
  $date = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node)->field_class_date->value->value();
  $name = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $instructor)->field_class_instructor->value();
  // Build a string of output that I want to display later in the $content array
  $classes_today = etc...
}
```

**(5)** Finally, I added the $classes_today string to the $content array:

```
$content['more_classes']['#prefix'] = '<h2 class="classes-on-this-day">Classes on this Day:</h2><div class="more-classes">';
$content['more_classes']['#markup'] = $more_classes;
$content['more_classes']['#weight'] = '4';
$content['more_classes']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi for this you can simply place a filter for date field in your view.

[image: Choose your date field and add to filters.]

Select Operator as " Is equal to" and then type "NOW" in the selection for filtering.

This should filter down your class content as per present/current date.

Comment: I don't want to filter classes to "NOW."  I want to filter them to the date of the class node being viewed, which is specified by field_class_date, which is attached to all classes.

Comment: oh all right...